# how to use itertools.product() to give one of the tuples as output each time instead of entire list of tuples at once?

Tags: python

I wanted to know whether there is any way to make `itertools.product()` to produce single tuple each time instead of producing entire result (list of tuples).

code:

```
desired = [1 for i in itertools.product([0,1],repeat=2) if (i.count(1)>i.count(0)]
```

When `repeat=2`, `itertools.product()` in the following code produces `(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)`.
The code will add `1` to desired list if number of `1`'s is more than number of `0`'s in the tuple under consideration.
after the execution of the code,
`desired=[1]` because only the tuple `(1,1)` satisfies the condition.

Same code will not work for `repeat=999`,because `itertools.product()` gives large output which cannot be handled by Python. Because of this reason, I want `itertools.product()` to produce only one item at a time not the entire list of items (which will be difficult to handle).
Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: `itertools.product` already produces only one item at a time. The memory problem is *your* fault, because of the giant list you're trying to build (and you'd never be able to finish even if you weren't trying to build a list - there are way too many tuples to go through. You need a smarter approach).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of repeat is to produce combinations/cartesian sets.

When you have `repeat=3` and list as `[0, 1]` then the result is

`000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111`

The number of elements is **2<sup>3</sup>**

When the `repeat` is **999** then there are 2<sup>999</sup> elements which is closely **5x10<sup>300</sup>**.

Each integer is 16 bytes in memory. There are 3x5x10<sup>300</sup> such integers in memory while doing so. Hence, the memory error.

NOTE: Cartesian product goes crazy with a large number of repeats. Be careful while using it.

Comment: is there any other built in function that I can use to achieve the same? or is it not possible at all due to memory error?

Comment: Do you need to produce the cartesian product for large repeats like 999? If yes, then you need a super-computer. XD

Comment: Basically, you'll need 16x15x10^300 bytes of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `itertools.product([0,1],repeat=2)` will give one element at a time. your list comprehension is iterating over all values and making list from it. You can use following concise syntax to return iterator, please notice "(" instead or "["

This way you can process one value at a time without loading all values in memory at once

```py
import itertools

desired_iter = (1 for i in itertools.product([0,1],repeat=2) if (i.count(1)>i.count(0)))


# then you can use "desired_iter" in for loop when needed and process 
# one value at a time
for i in desired_iter:
    print(i)
```

Comment: @user8735299 is this what you wanted or I understood it wrong?

Comment: Yes,Thank you,I don't know why but it still  gives me memory error.